# Python: Invalid RGBA argument 0.0 color points according to class

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, colormap

**Context**

I have some points

```
 points = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (10,2))
# array([[ 7.35906037,  6.50049804],
       [ 3.21883403,  3.81452312],
       [ 3.52107154,  1.68233797],
       [ 1.47699577,  6.01692348],
       [ 3.76051589,  0.25213394],
       [ 8.93701081,  5.20377479],
       [ 6.5347188 ,  2.12940006],
       [ 3.62550069,  5.80619507],
       [ 1.33393325,  5.0088937 ],
       [ 6.99034593,  7.40277623]])
```

and they are "classified" or labelled. This means that I have a list

```
    labels = np.random.randint(0,3, size = 10)
  # array([2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2])
```

which represents the labels (in order) of each point in `points`.

I also have some extra points

```
    extraPoints = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (3,2))
# array([[ 1.91211141,  3.71208978],
#   [ 8.10463536,  1.88948511],
#   [ 9.79796593,  3.39432552]])
```

basically each of these points determines the class label. It doesn't matter HOW it determined the label. But all you have to know is that each of these extra points is associated to one and only one label. So there is an equal number of extraPoints and label possibilities.

**problem**

I want to do a scatter plot. I want to assign a different color to each point in `extraPoints`, and hence this color will be the correspective to each class. This basically means that `extraPoints[0]` is associated with class `0`, `extraPoints[1]` is associated with class `1` and `extraPoints[2]` is associated with class `2`.

Also, I want to scatter plot the points in `points`. Remember that each point in `points` is associated with the correspective label in `labels`.
For instance `[ 7.35906037,  6.50049804]` is in class `2` and thus has the same color of `extraPoints[2] = [ 9.79796593,  3.39432552]`. Similarly the point `[ 3.21883403,  3.81452312]` in `points` is associated with class `0` in `labels` and thus has the same color of `extraPoints[0] = [ 1.91211141,  3.71208978]`

**My try**

I tried using the `c` argument in `plt.scatter()` however I don't really understand how it works, and sometimes it sort of works, sometimes it says "Invalid RGBA argument 0.0" but seems to be arbitrary..

Notice that to distinguish `points` from `extraPoints`, I will make `extraPoints` larger and with more transparency.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# I scatter the points, and assign c to labels. So hopefully each
# point that ends up in the same label will have the same 
# color? I  think this part is fine, although I am not sure
plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c = labels) 
plt.scatter(extraPoints[:,0], extraPoints[:,1], s = 100, alpha = 0.3, c = np.arange(len(extraPoints)))
```

As you can try out for yourself, for different executions (since every time we have random arrays) we might either get it right (or almost) or get the error in the title. Why does this happen?

**Extra -for the braves**

Given this context, imagine I had also some values

```
    values = np.random.uniform(0,50, size = 3)
# array([ 14.63459424,  37.41573654,  34.45202082])
```

I have the same number of values as I have types of labels and extraPoints (i.e. 3 in this case).  Now each of these is associated with the corresponding extraPoints. Thus the first value to the first extraPoint and so on..

I would like to do the above plot, but the colors will have a "gradient" that becomes, for instance, lighter for smaller values and darker for larger values (or the opposite). How can I do that? I read about colormaps, but I can't quite integrate it with my problem.

**Example**

For instance for the values above, we obtain:
[image: scatter]

As you can see, I have no control over the colors. Not only that, but I have no idea of which point is in which class (unless I go back and manually look at each point, but obviously I don't want this). This is why (and other reasons that I wont cover here) I want to color them based on a value in `values`. Specifically, I would like, say to have a range of values `[10, 20 30]` that can guide the color of my points, so that I know which class is "strongest"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*First problem*: the code does not run, since `np.random.uniform(0,10, size = 3)` gives a 1D array, while you later expect it to be 2D (`extraPoints[:,0]`).

*Second problem*: `labels` may have between 1 and 3 unique entries, hence `np.unique(labels)` may be of length 1 to 3 (e.g. `labels` may be all zeros, such that `np.unique(labels) == [0]`) such that you have more points than colors. However `c` expects either a single color argument or a list of values of the same length than the input coordinates.

*Third problem*: If supplying a list or array of length 3 or 4, it is not clear whether this should be a single RGB or RGBA color or a list of values to colormap. If you actually run into this problem or not, cannot be said for sure until you have solved the first and second problem.

Update: after the first two problems are solved, you are probably just looking for a colorbar and a useful colormap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

points = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (10,2))

labels = np.random.randint(0,3, size = 10)

extraPoints = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (3,2))

sc = plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c = labels) 
sc2 = plt.scatter(extraPoints[:,0], extraPoints[:,1], s = 144, alpha = 0.7, 
            c = np.arange(len(extraPoints)))

plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you want to have individual colors:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

points = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (10,2))

labels = np.random.randint(0,3, size = 10)

extraPoints = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (3,2))

colors=["red", "gold", "limegreen"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

sc = plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c = labels, cmap=cmap, vmin=-0.5,vmax=2.5 ) 
sc2 = plt.scatter(extraPoints[:,0], extraPoints[:,1], s = 144, alpha = 0.7, 
            c = np.arange(len(extraPoints)), cmap=cmap, vmin=-0.5,vmax=2.5)

plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=np.arange(len(extraPoints)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: First problem was a typo, corrected it. You are right, should be a 3x2 array

Comment: For the second problem I can use `c = np.arange(len(extraPoints))`

Comment: Thus fixing the second problem we will (possibly) have some `extraPoints` that have a color but no point in `points` has that color. That covers those cases.

Comment: Ok, so when we fix the first and second problem the way you say here, the code should work fine and the third problem is not present, correct?

Comment: The answer is "sort of". It works because we have that each point in `points` that belongs to a given label in `labels` has the same color and this color is the same color of the corresponding extra point in `extraPoints`. However I don't have any control over the colors. Not only that, but if I plot it, I have no way to know (unless I go and I check manually point by point) which label is which. This is why I would like to have some control over the colors, so that I can visually inspect which points in `points` are in which label. Thus I would like to solve the problem of...

Comment: ... assigning colors based on values in `values`. Does this makes sense?

Comment: I guess the only remaining problem is to obtain a colormap and a colorbar? In that case see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. However this is just a MWE, in reality I won't have only 3 classes, and I will have a different number of classes each time I run the code. So I need something that doesn't rely on me writing down theindividual colors

Comment: You may leave out the `colors` and `cmap` completely. Then a default colormap is chosen, I updated the answer with this even easier case.

Comment: Thank you. But I would still like to give it some values. It would be hard to explain why I want to do it, but I would like to have some control over the colormap. So given a list of values, I want to assign each of these values to one of the classes. And the colormap will give darker colors to bigger numbers and lighter to smaller ones

Comment: This looks more like the case where I use a ListedColormap above. I don't see where the problem lies.

Comment: I think I am not being clear enough :/Imagine now I have `values = [5,1,4]' and these values are associated with the classes so that for instance class `0` (given by `extraPoints[0]' and by the particles with the label equal to `0` ) will have value 5 and os on

Comment: Okay so now we have `3` classes given by the `3` points in `extraPoints`. Since the `labels` are created randomly, it could happen that we have less labels than `extraPoints`, but this doesn't matter. Now, imagine I have some values describing how strong each of the points in `extraPoints` is. The values are given by `values = [5,1,4]`. Thus I want to color the points in extraPoints (and the correspective points in `points`) based on their strength!
 (NOT ON THEIR CLASS NUMBER!)

Comment: The list of values is possibly different from the class values!

Comment: I'm affraid, I cannot follow. If `values` are the values according to which you would like to colorize the points, you would provide those to the `c` argument, `c= values`.

Comment: yes, except that I would mess up the order of the colors!

Comment: try it yourself

Comment: So for instance the labels are `np.array([2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2])` .  SO the values of the labels mix up and are repeated. However the value list is `values = [5,1,4]` and not something like `values = [4,5,1,4,4,1,1,5,1,4]`

Comment: I think "mess up the order of colors" is not a sufficient problem description. At least not one that I understand. I could imagine that at this point it is best to stop discussing. You would sort everything you have learnt so far about colormap and the `c` argument in your head and then ask a new clear question with a [mcve] of the issue. Possibly the actual problem is only to map `[5,1,4]` to `[4,5,1,4,4,1,1,5,1,4]` according to `[2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]`, but that would also be worth a new question, as it is unrelated to matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you again @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , you helped me a lot! I was wondering, how would I change the colormap? So for instance you wrote `colors = ['red', 'gold', 'limegreen']`, so I tried changing one of those colors to `blue` but nothing seems to change in the colors.

Comment: The first solution does not use the manual colors. I'm sorry, I did not pay attention to deleting those unused lines in the first solution above. I edited the answer now. In the second example, changing e.g. "gold" to "blue" would result in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzCc3.png). So which solution are you talking about and what would you like the output to look like?

Comment: That would look great! I found out I messed up something in the code ahah now it all works, thanks again!

Comment: I have another question: instead of using `labels = np.random.randint(0,3, size = 10)` for the labels, I tried using `labels = np.random.uniform(-1,1)` however it raises `Invalid RGBA argument: -0.99116826848912587`. Do you know why it can'y handle negative values? And how should I overcome this obstacle?

Comment: There is no problem of using negative labels. The question is more if it makes sense to use a single label.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest I managed to solve the problem. I know my explanation was really bad, but here I post it for someone who might find the same problem in the future:

**ImportanceOfBeingErnest solution**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

points = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (10,2))

labels = np.random.randint(0,3, size = 10)

extraPoints = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (3,2))

colors=["red", "gold", "limegreen"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

sc = plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c = labels, cmap=cmap, vmin=-0.5,vmax=2.5 ) 
sc2 = plt.scatter(extraPoints[:,0], extraPoints[:,1], s = 144, alpha = 0.7, 
            c = np.arange(len(extraPoints)), cmap=cmap, vmin=-0.5,vmax=2.5)

plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=np.arange(len(extraPoints)))

plt.show()
```

**My add-in that does what I want**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

points = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (10,2))

labels = np.random.randint(0,3, size = 10)

extraPoints = np.random.uniform(0,10, size = (3,2))
# CREATE VALUES
values = np.random.uniform(0,50, size=3)

colors=["red", "gold", "limegreen"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

sc = plt.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1], c = np.array([values[j] for j in labels]), cmap=cmap, vmin=-0.5,vmax=2.5 ) 
sc2 = plt.scatter(extraPoints[:,0], extraPoints[:,1], s = 144, alpha = 0.7, 
            c = values, cmap=cmap, vmin=-0.5,vmax=2.5)

plt.colorbar(sc, ticks=np.arange(len(extraPoints)))

plt.show()
```

The difference is that the colors in `sc` are now determined by the values in `values` in the same order of the `labels`, and at the same time, the points in `extraPoints` are being colored with the strength and order of values in `values`.